# For loop enumerate. Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested, enumerate

Right now I have a JSON with a list containing two dictionaries. This code allows the user to search through the list via index number, retrieving a dictionary. Currently I get two printed results one for each dictionary, for example if I typed the index number 1, I get: No Index Number and then dictionary one printed out. Instead of this I would like to get only one result printed either the found dictionary or 1 error. Should I not use enumerate?

Here is my JSON(questions) containing a list of 2 dicts.

```
[{
    "wrong3": "Nope, also wrong",
    "question": "Example Question 1",
    "wrong1": "Incorrect answer",
    "wrong2": "Another wrong one",
    "answer": "Correct answer"
}, {
    "wrong3": "0",
    "question": "How many good Matrix movies are there?",
    "wrong1": "2",
    "wrong2": "3",
    "answer": "1"
}]
```

Here is my code

```
f = open('question.txt', 'r')
questions = json.load(f)
f.close()


value = inputSomething('Enter Index number: ')



for index, question_dict in enumerate(questions):

   if index == int(value):
      print(index, ') ', question_dict['question'],
         '\nCorrect:', question_dict['answer'],
         '\nIncorrect:', question_dict['wrong1'],
         '\nIncorrect:', question_dict['wrong2'],
         '\nIncorrect:', question_dict['wrong3'])
      break

   if not index == int(value):
      print('No index exists')
```

Comment: Quick note: `continue` can't be used outside a loop

Comment: Ahhh. I have copied this from a larger piece. Amended @Zizouz212

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Use `with` to make sure the file is closed properly
with open('question.txt', 'r') as f:
    questions = json.load(f)

value = inputSomething('Enter Index number: ')
queried_index = int(value)

# Since `questions` is a list, why don't you just *index` it with the input value
if 0 <= queried_index < len(questions):
    question_dict = questions[queried_index]
    # Let `print` take care of the `\n` for you
    print(index, ') ', question_dict['question'])
    print('Correct:', question_dict['answer'])
    print('Incorrect:', question_dict['wrong1'])
    print('Incorrect:', question_dict['wrong2'])
    print('Incorrect:', question_dict['wrong3'])
else:
    print('No index exists')
```

Comment: Did you copy that `0 <` mistake from the other answer? :-P

Comment: Going off schlezzz15 code I was trying to work out how to index with the input, just was not sure of the syntax. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Youngn' Or you can use `0 <= queried_index` instead.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, I don't think you need to use `enumerate`.
I personally don't think you should loop over the `questions`.

Why not doing:

```
# assuming the user enters integers from 1 to N.
user_index = int(value) - 1
if -1 < user_index < len(questions):
    # print the question
else:
    print('No index exists')
```

And while we are in it, why not using `with` keyword:

```
with open('question.txt', 'r') as f:
    questions = json.load(f)
```

instead of doing `close`:

```
f = open('question.txt', 'r')
questions = json.load(f)
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes I thought enumerate was the issue but couldn't figure out anyway other avenues. Much obliged.

Comment: No problem, amigo ;)
Enjoyed helping you out.

Comment: Yes I changed to -1 earlier, though -1 does not print 'No index exists'